# Which linux distro is great for my old computer?

Tags: software-recommendation

Can you suggest me some Linux Distros made for old computers?

My OLD PC config:

Pentium 4 - 2.3 GHz

RAM - 512 MB

HD - 80 GB

:D

Comment: This question is moot since most everyone here would recommend Ubuntu or a derivative. If you're looking for an answer which encompasses more than Ubuntu may I recommend [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)